# Android onActivityResult is never launched

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, phonegap-plugins

I am sorry for asking  the same again, but after looking for the answer I didn´t a code that works properly.

ñThis is the main function where I call the activity:

```
package com.phonegap.CameraPluginTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.phonegap.DroidGap;

public class CameraPluginTest2_3Activity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        try{
            CustomCamera camera = new CustomCamera(this);
            appView.addJavascriptInterface(camera, "CustomCamera");
            //camera.Cameratest();
            //camera.startCamera(50);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("RapportsError",  "error" + ex.toString());
        }
    }

    public class CustomCamera{
        private Context context;

        public CustomCamera (Context context){
            this.context = context;

        }

        public void Cameratest() {
            Log.e("RapportsError",  "Cameratest");

        }
        public void startCamera(int quality)
        {
            Log.e("RapportsError",  "intent");
            try{

                Intent i = new Intent(context, CameraPreview.class);

                i.setAction("android.intent.action.PICK");
                i.putExtra("quality", quality);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                Log.e("RapportsError",  "despues de intent" );
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("RapportsError",  "error" + ex.toString());
            }
        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent intent)
        {
            String data;            
            Log.e("RapportsError",  "ON ACTIVITY RESULT " + reqCode);
            //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            if (resCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                data = intent.getStringExtra("picture"); 
                Log.e("RapportsError",  "error" + data);
                // Send the graphic back to the class that needs it
                //launcher.processPicture(data);
            }
            else
            {
                //launcher.failPicture("Did not complete!");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is the class that is called

```
package com.phonegap.CameraPluginTest;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.graphics.YuvImage;
import android.os.Environment;

public class CameraPreview extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private static final String TAG = "PhoneGapCamera";
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    private RelativeLayout root;

    Camera mCamera;
    boolean mPreviewRunning = false;

    int quality;
    Intent mIntent;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams containerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams surfaceParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0.0F);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        root = new RelativeLayout(this);
        root.setLayoutParams(containerParams);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
        mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(surfaceParams);
        root.addView(mSurfaceView);

        Button stopButton = new Button(this);
        stopButton.setText("click");
        buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        buttonParams.rightMargin = 5;
        buttonParams.topMargin = 5;

        stopButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
        root.addView(stopButton);

        setContentView(root);

        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);                    
        mIntent = this.getIntent();

        quality = mIntent.getIntExtra("quality", 100);


        stopButton.setOnClickListener(mSnapListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener mSnapListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
        }
    };

    //public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    //    MenuItem item = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "goto gallery");
    //    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    //        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    //            Uri target = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media");
    //            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, target);
    //            startActivity(intent);
    //            return true;
    //        }
    //    });
    //    return true;
    //}

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);        
    }

    /*
     * We got the data, send it back to PhoneGap to be handled and processed.
     * 
     */

   // Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
   //     public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera c) {
   //         Log.e(TAG, "PICTURE CALLBACK: data.length = " + data.length);
   //         storeAndExit(data);

   //     }
    //};

    Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {        
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera _camera) {                        
              storeAndExit(data,_camera);
              Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");                            
        }
      };

    /*
     * We can't just store and exit, because Android freezes up when we try to cram a picture across a process in a Bundle.
     * We HAVE to compress this data and send back the compressed data  
     */
    public void storeAndExit(byte[] data,Camera _camera)
    {       
          FileOutputStream outStream = null;          
          String fotoName = new String();
          try {
          fotoName="wy"+System.currentTimeMillis();
          outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                  "/sdcard/%s.png", fotoName));
          outStream.write(data);
          outStream.close();
          Log.e(TAG, "PICTURE CALLBACK: fotoName" + fotoName + "data.length = " + data.length);
          String js_out = new String( "/sdcard/" + fotoName + ".png");

          mIntent.putExtra("picture", js_out);
              //setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
          this.setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
         // Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(outStream);
         // storeAndExit(data);
              finish();
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
          }           
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {         
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    protected void onStop()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStop");
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        //mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");

        // XXX stopPreview() will crash if preview is not running
        if (mPreviewRunning) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }

        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(0);


        p.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
        mCamera.setParameters(p);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = true;
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = false;
        mCamera.release();
    }

    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();
            YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(),
                    size.width, size.height, null);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getPath() + "/out.jpg");
            FileOutputStream filecon = new FileOutputStream(file);
            image.compressToJpeg(
                    new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), 90,
                    filecon);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast
                    .makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), 1000);
            toast.show();
        }
    }


}
```

This one is the Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.phonegap.CameraPluginTest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true" >
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraPluginTest2_3Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraPreview" 
            android:label="CameraPreviewLabel" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>                
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The main problem is that I am able to take the photo, so the call for the class is working, but the onActivityResult is not called.

Do you have a clue?

Thank you very much and sorry for asking the same again, but I don´t see where is the problem.

Regards

Comment: have you checked if onActivityResult is not really called, or your resultCode and/or requestCode just doesn't match the one expected by the method?

Comment: There is one probability if everything is correct.Please put  onActivityResult in the superclass i.e. in DroidGap class with a logcat message and comment here

Comment: Please add some code of CameraPreview.

Comment: Are you sure that CameraPluginTest2_3Activity isn't finished somewhere after calling startCamera?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to start with the @Simon MacDonald advise and I will tell you the results.

Answer (score 4):

Saw your answer for your problem.. The way you can get your Activity to come back to your plug in is to make sure that :

```
this.cordova.setActivityResultCallback(MyActivity.this);
```

is called before you do the startActivityForResult()... call. Something that 
really was bothering me that no one seemed to have answered anywhere. Had to find it out for myself.

SF

Comment: What is this "MyActivity"? If it an Android Activity, then the `void org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface.setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin arg0)`, the method takes a CordovaPlugin arg. In which java file I have to call this method, since Android Activity doesn't have a `cordova` instance to call this.cordova.

Answer (score 1):

If you have onActivityResult() in your main Activity, you must ensure it calls the method of its parent to correctly process the plugins:

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {
                    //or 'extends DroidGap' based on Cordova version

    //...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == MyCustomActivity) {
                    doMyCustomActivity(requestCode);
            }
            else { //call onActivityResult() of the plugins
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            }
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it is my advice to you to change your class CustomCamera to extend the Plugin interface that PhoneGap provides. We handle all the little gotchas in communicating between the native and JavaScript layers. There are issues that will pop up when using addJavascriptInterface that you'll have to work around including, the keyboard showing up reloads your app, the interface does not work on some versions of the simulator, etc. Just use our Plugin API as it will be much easier for you.

[How to create a Plugin for Android](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android)

Look at the src of our [Camera code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CameraLauncher.java) in PhoneGap as we just launch the picture taking intent for Android and you can use the same approach but launch your intent instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get onActivityResult to work until I've change the launchMode in the AndroidManifest.xml

This one is **not working**:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

*standard* and *singleTop* worked fine for me.

I see you don't have a launchMode in your manifest so I'm not sure it'll help in your case. But I hope it might help anyone else stuck with that issue.